# ProcessPoolExecutor with loky in Windows, one process is not terminated

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

In my quest to make a parallelised python program (written on Linux) truly platform independent, I was looking for python packages that would parallelise seamlessly in windows. So, I found [joblib](https://github.com/joblib/joblib), which looked like a godsend, because it worked on Windows without having hundreds of annoying pickling errors.

Then I ran into a problem that the processes spawned by joblib would continue to exist even if there were no parallel jobs running. This is a problem because in my code, there are multiple uses of `os.chdir()`. If there are processes running after the jobs end, there is no way to do `os.chdir()` on them, so it is not possible to delete the temporary folder where the parallel processes were working. This issue has been noted in this previous post: [Joblib Parallel doesn't terminate processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495271/joblib-parallel-doesnt-terminate-processes)

After some digging, I figured out that the problem is coming from the backend [loky](https://github.com/joblib/loky), which reuses the pool of processes, so keeps them alive.

So, I used loky directly, by calling the `loky.ProcessPoolExecutor()` instead of using `loky.get_reusable_executor()` that joblib uses. The `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `loky` seems to be a reimplementation of python's `concurrent.futures` and uses similar semantics.

This works fine, however, there is one python process that seems to still stick around, even after shutting down the `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Minimal example with interactive python on Windows (use interactive shell because otherwise all the processes will terminate on exit):

```py
>>> import loky
>>> import time
>>> def f():  # just some dummy function
...   time.sleep(10)
...   return 0
...
>>> pool = loky.ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
```

At this point, there is only one python process running (please note the PID in task manager).

[image]

Then, submit a job to the process pool (which returns a `Future` object).

```py
>>> task = pool.submit(f)
>>> task
<Future at 0x11ad6f37640 state=running>
```

There are 5 processes now. One is the main process (PID=16508). There are three worker processes in the pool. But there is another extra process. I am really not sure what it is doing there.

[image]

After getting results, shutting the pool down removes the three worker processes. But not the one extra process.

```
>>> task.result()
0
>>> pool.shutdown()  # you can add kill_workers=True, but does not change the result
```

[image]

The new python process with PID=16904 is still running. I have tried looking through the source code of loky, but I cannot figure out where that additional process is being created (and why it is necessary). Is there any way to tell this loky process to shutdown? (I do not want to resort to `os.kill` or some other drastic way of terminating process e.g. with `SIGTERM`, I want to do it programmatically if I can)