# Convert joblib Parallel to multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I am currently using joblib's Parallel and it is working great but running into issues when I run in the server because [the processes are not killed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495271/joblib-parallel-doesnt-terminate-processes)

I have a function that is called on a list of tuples.

I will use a simplified example with numbers but my actual function is more complicated and thats why multiprocessing is necessary -- I have a tuple that has two numbers. `function_to_call` will return the product and the sum of the two numbers

```
lst_of_tuples = [(10, 5), (0.5, 10), (8, 3)]
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def multiprocess(lst_of_tuples):
    return Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(function_to_call)(t[0], t[1]) for t in lst_of_tuples)

products, sums = list(map(list, zip(*multiprocess(my_lst))))
```

The expected result of products is (50, 5, 24) and sums is (15, 10.5, 11).

Is it possible to convert this line of code with multiprocessing pool so I can use pool.close() and pool.join() and kill all processes?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def function_to_call(x, y):
    return x * y, x + y

def multiprocess(lst_of_tuples):
    # No sense in creating more processes than can be used:
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), len(lst_of_tuples))
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    results = pool.starmap(function_to_call, lst_of_tuples)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst_of_tuples = [(10, 5), (0.5, 10), (8, 3)]
    products, sums = zip(*multiprocess(lst_of_tuples))
    print(products, sums)
```

**Note**

The call `pool.close()` will prevent further tasks from being submitted, then wait for all submitted tasks to complete and then the processes will terminate by themselves. The call to `pool.join()` then just waits (blocks) until all processes have terminated. In the code above, after the `map` call returns there are no uncompleted tasks left and so the processes will immediately terminate upon calling `pool.close()`.

You can also call `pool.terminate()` to kill all pool processes immediately. This call will automatically be done when you use the pool as a context handler, as in:

```py
    with Pool() as pool:
        # submit tasks
        ...
    # on exit from the above block a call to pool.terminate() is made
```